# What to do with the potentially Riddler-Allied Cop?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

When walking through the GCPD, I found this officer, highlighted in green (as the thugs you can interrogate for Riddler Intel are).

[image: "Talk to Officer JT Wicker"]

I can't beat him up, or seemingly report him in any way. Is there anything I can do with him, or is this likely just a glitch of some kind?

Comment: Highly likely not a glitch, this is most likely used just to show you how corrupt the police force is

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He is, in fact, a Riddler Informant.  Hit the "Interrogate" button you'd usually use on Riddler Informants.  (<kbd>RMB</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Δ</kbd> depending on platform, as referenced in the other answer.)

Batman will grab him, and the other two cops will draw their weapons.  Quickly, though the guy will confess to being an informant and give you the goods.

The other two officers reference this event if you talk to them afterwards, and will apologize for drawing their weapons on Batman.

Answer (score 3):

You could try pressing Counter, as this generally interrogates the informant.

Counter, by default is:
PC:  <kbd>RMB</kbd>
PS4:  <kbd>Δ</kbd>
XB1: <kbd>Y</kbd>

Comment: Ah, I was going to say I tried this, but I believe I tried attacking him first. Will try when I get back to my PC.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.  This is the correct answer.  It worked for me a quick google search will support this answer.

Comment: @sommerjj - Original post quality was arguably low.